# How to change padding of a table within markdown?

Tags: css, markdown, jekyll

I'm building tables using Jekyll Spaceship and am not happy with how much space a single row takes up. My tables are quite simple which I have in a markdown file.

```
|              Stage | Direct Products | ATP Yields |
| -----------------: | --------------: | ---------: |
|         Glycolysis |          2 ATP              ||
| Pyruvaye oxidation |          2 NADH |      5 ATP |
|  Citric acid cycle |          2 ATP              ||
|                               30--32 ATP        |||
```

My problem is that the text takes up not even half the cell space with padding above and below the text.

How would I decrease the padding in a markdown file for rows in a table?

I've also tried adding the following ...

```
<style>
table, th, td {
    padding: 1px;
}
</style>

<div class="bettertd">

| .... placed markdown tables here ... |

</div>
```

And this put this in CSS ...

```
.features table {
    styles="padding:1px";
}
```

But didn't work.

Comment: Hope the follow answer could help you settle your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At First, you can specific a class for the table as below:

```
|              Stage | Direct Products | ATP Yields |
| -----------------: | --------------: | ---------: |
|         Glycolysis |          2 ATP              ||
| Pyruvaye oxidation |          2 NADH |      5 ATP |
|  Citric acid cycle |          2 ATP              ||
|                               30--32 ATP        |||
{:.custom-table}
```

And Second step, you need to add your custom css styles to the your jekyll theme css file (usually under the `_sass` folder and named `*.sass`).

```
//...

.custom-table th, .custom-table td {
   padding: 1px;
   // any style you want ...
}
```

Or add to the head of your theme post layout (usually under the `_layout` folder and called `*.html`).

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <style>
      .custom-table th, .custom-table td {
        padding: 1px;
        // any style you want ...
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
<html>
```

Or even you using the `element-processor` of `jekyll-spaceship` to modify the element style ([Click for more usage details](https://github.com/jeffreytse/jekyll-spaceship#9-modifying-element-usage)), adding the config to your `_config.yml` as below:

```
jekyll-spaceship:
  element-processor:
    css:
      - [.custom-table th, .custom-table td]:  # Select the th, td nodes of custom table
          props:                               # Replace element properties
            style:                             # Add style attributes (Hash Style)
              padding: 1px                     # Add padding 
              # font-size: '1.2em'             # Add any style that you want
```